# Command substitution using grep'ed and sed'ed tail -f output as argument source into 'at' command

Tags: ufw, tail

This is for a home surveillance system, headless server running Ubuntu 15.04, and I want its security to be exemplary. I envision a command line solution (with optional script, if absolutely necessary) monitoring IP probes from lookers/hackers logged in my ufw.log and blacklisting them in real time if they don't port knock correctly in time.  Thus far, I have:

```
tail -n+1 -F /var/log/ufw.log | 
  grep -v --line-buffered '0.0.0.0' | 
    sed -e 's/BLOCK/&/g' -e 's/.*SRC\=//g' -e 's/\ DST.*//g'
```

which outputs to stdout a live stream of probe hitting IPs.  These are the IPs I want to blacklist x (3?) minutes from 'now'.  That gives the legitimate users time to get whitelisted first by port knocking.  I'm using ufw insert command for black- and whitelisting which means whichever listing happens first dominates.

The whitelisting portion is working fine right now.  Next I want to develop the 'at' command that correctly executes the `ufw insert 1 deny from x.x.x.x` command where x.x.x.x comes from the aforementioned tail command.

My first attempt is something like

```
ufw insert 1 deny from $(tail -n+1 -F /var/log/ufw.log | 
   grep -v --line-buffered '0.0.0.0' | 
   sed -e 's/BLOCK/&/g' -e 's/.*SRC\=//g' -e 's/\ DST.*//g');
ufw reload | 
   at now +3 minute`
```

but no `at` command gets generated as shown by `at -l`.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong with that command?

NEW THOUGHT - I am thinking that the `tail -F` command must be the beginning.  Any other way seems to only process a single line from the ufw log file.

For the curious of you, the port knocking rules I have in place now can and do blacklist, but very limitedly because I have to define the probing behavior in advance in the rules.  So if they go for ports 22 twice or 21 twice or 443 twice, they get blacklisted now.  But I see probings going on for ports in the 55xxx range, 4 or 5 probes to different ports.  I don't see how these can reasonably be characterized in firewall rules, but what I certainly *can* do is log with ufw all the probes falling through the whitelist and blacklist into the final deny+log section.  I want to give them x minutes to port knock correctly, then the 'ufw' part of this command scheduled by the 'at' part will execute.

Thank you!

muru got me very close.  Here is the current state of progress, but note that ufw has a propensity for this error:  `ERROR: initcaps

[Errno 2] iptables: Chain already exists.`  So I don't think it works robustly enough with iptables to handle this integration very well.  I think it best to use iptable commands directly instead of having ufw interpret.

```sh
tail -F /var/log/ufw.log | 
  grep -v --line-buffered '0.0.0.0' | 
  sed -e 's/BLOCK/&/g' -e 's/.*SRC\=//g' -e 's/\ DST.*//g' | 
  while read IP; do
    echo ufw insert 1 deny from "$IP" | 
      at now +3 minute;
    echo ufw reload | at now +3 minute; 
  done
```

NOTE THE BACKTICKS WOULDN'T DISPLAY IN THIS TEXT BUT I NEEDED TO ADD THEM I THINK.  THEY BELONG PRIOR TO EACH ECHO COMMAND AND AFTER EACH MINUTE KEYWORD.

The way this fails now has to do with 'tail -F' piped into the 'while' construct: with every line appended to the ufw.log file, the ENTIRE file is re-fed into the 'while' loop instead of just that newly appended line.  I have searched my heart out and cannot locate the way around this. Help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix I needed: `stdbuf -o0` for sed and awk contained in the command line, like this:

tail -F /var/log/ufw.log|grep --line-buffered......|**stdbuf -o0** sed.....|**stdbuf -o0** awk......|

Can use `stdbuf -o0` with grep, too, instead of --line-buffered.  That is what `stdbuf -o0` does - it line buffers, which is what the command needed in my case.  Of course, the rest of the command needed to be assembled and echo'd into 'at', but that part was straightforward enough for me (using awk heavily) once I got the line-buffering aspect conquered.  I did end up needing a script for easy manual entry as well of these IP addresses to blacklist, along with an additional task or two as I mention below.

I start the process @reboot with the afore-described command in crontab tail-ing /var/log/kern.log where iptables logs the probing packets.  That command sends each probing IP address with time and packet details into a bash script.  That bash script, in building the final iptables blacklisting command, tails the /var/log/knockd.log for knock sequence successfully begun ('Stage n') in which case it sends a version of the script-constructed blacklist-IP command into 'at' for blacklist entry 3 minutes later.  Otherwise the script-constructed blacklist-IP command runs immediately. If port knocking succeeds, the IP gets whitelisted [FUTURE - which prevents the scheduled blacklist-IP command from succeeding (the version of the command scheduled in 'at' will begin by checking for presence of IP in whitelist)].

I am putting the finishing touches in, like the 'at' scheduled version to check for whitelist presence.  I stopped using ufw and simplified my life by controlling iptables directly.  No fail2ban, either, because it was too much bloat for my liking just to secure a private, whitelist only system.  Now whenever any port on my system is probed just a single time, that IP address gets blacklisted.  Here are some lines from my iptables, blacklist follows the whitelist, not shown are LOG and DROP rules at the end (DROP only needed if policy = ACCEPT).  Later I'll compact into subnets when I feel like it.

(Sorry the formatting got lost)
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       xxx.72.26.233        0.0.0.0/0
2      592 53357 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3       98  5922 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
4        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
5        1    60 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       xx.179.31.188        0.0.0.0/0            /* knocked Sun Oct 25 16:33:53 CDT 2015 */
6        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       xxx.32.31.196        0.0.0.0/0            /* isp server Mon Oct 26 12:43:59 CDT 2015 */
7        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       xxx.142.225.5        0.0.0.0/0            /* isp server Mon Oct 26 12:43:45 CDT 2015 */
8        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       xxx.32.31.195        0.0.0.0/0            /* isp server Mon Oct 26 12:43:31 CDT 2015 */
9        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       xxx.72.26.254        0.0.0.0/0            /* isp server Mon Oct 26 12:43:11 CDT 2015 */
10       1   118 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       185.86.148.68        0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 22:29:53 PROTO=UDP SPT=56177 DPT=1900 */
11       0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       184.105.247.220      0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 22:22:30 PROTO=UDP SPT=53700 DPT=53413 */
12       0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       195.211.154.179      0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 22:21:49 PROTO=TCP SPT=48465 DPT=21320 */
13       2   120 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       75.111.59.88         0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 22:21:37 PROTO=TCP SPT=35727 DPT=23 */
14       0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       74.82.47.16          0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 22:17:34 PROTO=TCP SPT=38695 DPT=27017 */
15       0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       1.93.3.124           0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 22:16:33 PROTO=TCP SPT=1414 DPT=1433 */
16       0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       184.105.139.96       0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 22:12:42 PROTO=UDP SPT=51153 DPT=123 */
17       0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       121.230.163.125      0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 21:57:06 PROTO=ICMP */
18       0     0 DROP       all  --  eth0   *       120.132.50.66        0.0.0.0/0            /* kern.log Oct 27 21:53:30 PROTO=TCP SPT=51864 DPT=1023 */

Answer (score 2):

Unless `ufw reload` and `ufw insert` output a set of commands that reloads the firewall, piping it to `at` wouldn't be what you want.

Did you mean:

```
echo ufw insert 1 deny from $(tail -n+1 -F /var/log/ufw.log | 
   grep -v --line-buffered '0.0.0.0' | 
   sed -e 's/BLOCK/&/g' -e 's/.*SRC\=//g' -e 's/\ DST.*//g') | at now +3 minute
echo ufw reload | at now +3 minute
```

Or, combined:

```
at now +3 minute <<EOF
ufw insert 1 deny from $(tail -n+1 -F /var/log/ufw.log | grep -v --line-buffered '0.0.0.0' | sed -e 's/BLOCK/&/g' -e 's/.*SRC\=//g' -e 's/\ DST.*//g')
ufw reload
EOF
```

Comment: the ufw reload and insert do reload the firewall, but no they don't refer to a "set" of commands

Comment: I'm trying your second suggestion.  I have high hopes......

Comment: Using  your second suggestion, I'm not seeing an 'at' entry with 'at -l' showing up when it should.

Comment: @kenneth558 that is extremely odd. Something wrong with your `at`?

Comment: I tested my 'at' from command line before I even started.  Note that I did see a single 'at' entry once, then later two of them, but neither made the ufw table changes.  Note also that I don't yet know how to see the queued command details, so I don't know if the scheduled ufw command is error-free.  Right now, some hits are coming in without any 'at' activity shown in 'at -l'

Comment: I'm out of time. Later....

Comment: It must be noted that the simple form `at now +3 minute ufw insert 1 deny from 111.73.45.126` doesn't even work.  Error:  `syntax error. Last token seen: u
Garbled time`.  Quoting doesn't help, either

Comment: Just now tried your first answer using echo. The echo method DOES get 'at' to schedule non-command-substituted ufw commands.  Next step is for me to test the full answer with tail -f and all.

Comment: Using the echo method, I tried to cat the log instead of tail -F: only a single entry was made by 'at' out of a file of scores of lines of IP addresses.  By the same token, I've never seen ongoing entries from tail -F either.  That is one shortfall of muru's answer.  The next shortfall is that whatever scheduled command it was did not produce any results when it ran.  I wish I knew how to view the content of queued commands to know for sure if the command in queue was grammatically correct.

Comment: @kenneth558 for that, perhaps you should run a `while read` loop piped after the `tail ...`, so that each time a new entry pops up, it gets added.

Comment: I know that would work, but the reason I have been shying away from that method is the cpu overhead for it.  Do you think it is a lightweight enough solution for a server that has to perform very intensive "almost real-time" image processing?

Comment: @kenneth558 I don't know. How many entries so you expect to be added each second?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29523/discussion-between-kenneth558-and-muru).